# How to fix "TypeError: categories.map is not a function" error in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, dictionary

I keep getting this error that `categories.map` is not a function but I don't see why. I am setting categories to the data received from an API call but keep getting this error.
Also, is there a way to call the children of a parent object easily? the API data is nested about 4-5 levels deep, and they all have different names, so how would I go about iterating through all of them?

Example of what `response.data` looks like in the console (with some the nested objects opened up)

[image]

Here's my component:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categories: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories")
      .then(response => this.setState({ categories: response.data }));
  } 

  render() {
    let categories = this.state.categories;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {categories.map((m, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                {m.children && <Menu categories={m.children} />}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

EDIT: When I use `Object.keys` it gives me the error "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys...)" and then lists all keys within the objects I'm calling. Does anyone know how I can call the function (possibly recursively?) to apply this to all the objects within objects?

Here is my updated code:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false,
    categories: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories")
      .then(response => this.setState({ categories: response.data}));
  } 

  render() {
    const { categories } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(categories).map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <span>{categories[item]}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Can you console log the response? I believe categories is returned as an object and not an array, hence, you are getting that error

Comment: It looks like your response data is an object `{key: value}` with key value pairs. The `map` method is available on Array types only. You might want to use `for(let m in categories)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your properties object to array and handle it.

```
let result = Object.entries(data).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ [k]: v }));
```

Change to

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories")
      .then(response => this.setState({ 
       categories: Object.entries(response.data).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ [k]: v }) }));
  }
```

Comment: I see, I don't think I've ever used the map function for not an array so I didn't realize this was a problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: When I do it like this, it gives me the error "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys..." and then lists all keys within the objects I'm calling. Would you have any idea of how I can call my component recursively to apply to all objects within objects?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `response.data` is not `array` but it is a `json` object.

You can map based on the keys using the following code:

```
Object.keys(categories).map((key, index) => {
  console.log(categories[key]);
});
```